# How do you use sbt-pgp with a different command to call gpg? I have tried gpgCommand with no success

Tags: scala, sbt, gnupg, pgp, sbt-sonatype

I am using [sbt-pgp](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp) in our ci pipeline and want to use `Global / gpgCommand :=` to specify a different gpg version to call than the OS default. OS default path uses gpg version 1.x and I want to call gpg2 for version 2.x.

Following the README.md of [sbt-pgp](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp) i added `Global / gpgCommand :=` to `~/.sbt/gpg.sbt`, when I do nothing happens and the original gpg command is still called.

I then tried moving `Global / gpgCommand :=` to the `build.sbt` and tried `$HOME/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt` and I get this error:

`build.sbt:25: error: not found: value gpgCommand`

any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Thanks for all help all.

for `gpgCommand` I have tried:

```
Global / gpgCommand := "/usr/bin/gpg2"
```

Also tried:

```
Global / gpgCommand := (baseDirectory.value / "gpg.sh").getAbsolutePath
```

where `gpg.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

gpg2 $@
```

Comment: discussion at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/issues/133